# Bandwidth between AWS and Heroku

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I am seeing  "localhost like" latencies between Heroku and AWS. Is bandwidth between Heroku and AWS Cloud in the same region calculated as "out" bandwidth and is paid ?

Answer (score 3):

> I am seeing "localhost like" latencies between Heroku and AWS.

Unless things have changed dramatically, Heroku runs in AWS, so this would make sense.

> Is bandwidth between Heroku and AWS Cloud in the same region calculated as "out" bandwidth and is paid?

The [pricing tables](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) suggest that this would be based on the rules for data both in and out, from EC2 to EC2, within the same region. In us-east-1, this is $0.01/GB each direction.  This is substantially less than the cost of data outbound to the Internet.

Note that there are two different pricing rules depending on whether the availability zone is the same or different, but the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/) points out that there is no official way of determining whether "my" us-east-1b is the same as "your" us-east-1b, since the availability zone names are shuffled across different accounts... but the cost seems equivalent either way, since even if you're in the same A/Z, you're still using public or elastic IPs.

I am not affiliated with AWS so the only way to get an authoritative answer on this question is to consult your AWS account manager (if you have one) or AWS support.  Be sure to enable detailed billing, and monitor your usage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there could be latency for sure. Both communicate using public internet speed which depends on various factors.
2. Yes, the transfer is considered as network out and it definitely paid. 
   Internal traffic with an AWS region between AWS resources maybe free based on various conditions.